# JDK 1.7 64-bit Inflater throws Invalid Code Length set

Tags: java, zip

We are facing a weird problem on migrating from JDK 1.7 32-bit to 64-bit. In our app we using JDK Zip library to compress and decompress byte[] and prepare a QR code (using zxing) library. Everything runs fine on JDK 1.7 32-bit but on JDK 1.7 inflating fails with the following Exception:

```
java.util.zip.DataFormatException: invalid code lengths set
at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateBytes(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:259)
at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:280)
```

The same behaviour is seen in JDK 1.8 32-bit.

Relevant code

```
public static byte[] compress(String s) {
    Deflater comp = new Deflater();

    comp.setInput(s.getBytes());

    comp.finish();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(s.length());

    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    try {
        while (!(comp.finished())) {
            int count = comp.deflate(buf);
            bos.write(buf, 0, count);
        }
        bos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    byte[] compressedData = bos.toByteArray();

    return compressedData;
}

public static byte[] decompress(byte[] b) {
    Inflater decomp = new Inflater();

    decomp.setInput(b);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(b.length);

    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    try {
        while (!(decomp.finished())) {
            int count = decomp.inflate(buf);
            bos.write(buf, 0, count);
        }
        bos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    byte[] decompressedData = bos.toByteArray();
    return decompressedData;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: We also had problems with jdk-zip-lib. It was a software for exchanging messages between systems through middleware software, which has a certain size limit for its messages. Those systems were windows/linux/unix and also different jdk's and/or jre's... in the end, we switched to commons-compress,...

Comment: jdk zip lib has many bugs, we encountered the same as slowy, switch to common-compress

Comment: Thank you guys. Unfortunately switching is not an option for me. A lot of documents have already been generated using the above scheme and they would be rendered useless if we switch. Nevertheless, this is a good suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Your compress method is catching exceptions but not logging them.  Perhaps the compression is failing too, but you don't notice it because you are not logging